# Can I apply CSS filters ONLY on image sections?

Tags: html, css, blur, svg-filters

I have a full screen background-image

```
.bg { 
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%; 
    min-width: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

and want to apply a CSS filter, personally I would like to use a blur effect, at the same position as my body

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Here's an example:

[image: screenshot]

I want to write text over the blurred container.

Comment: take a div, position it there and use opacity to make the image blur

Comment: @Hushme that won't really blur the background though, just fade the colour slightly.

Comment: @Hushme Yeah, thanks. I already tried this, but can you show me an example where the **text is not (also) blurred**?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681857/blurring-an-image-via-css

Comment: it if you use opacity wisely than it will blur according to your requirement

Comment: ok let me try in few min

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Hey, you edited my question and commented it below...but is it possible to give me an example (colour slightly) 'cause I didn't understand :-)

Comment: @DevlshOne This is not a duplicate. The OP is asking about how to blur a section of an image.

Comment: Could you use three separate images adjacently?

Comment: @Asad: Mmmmh...it would work...than?

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs Yes, you would blur the center one, but leave the ones on the sides unchanged.

Comment: Question: is your background image scaled to fit the screen, or is it a huge background image that is displayed at original size?

Comment: @andi: scaled to fit the screen ;)

Comment: darn, I just did a good one if it weren't scaled: http://jsfiddle.net/fydr4/  But this is fun, I'll keep playing.

Comment: @andi: Hey great stuff! Just write it as an answer and you'll get accepted when you change it to this: background: url("http://lorempixel.com/900/800") no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QvSng/6/

**CSS**

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
body:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255)  no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs LOL, you need to interpret an answer. You only add no-repeat center center fixed and background-size: cover; to my answer.  That was the first by 2 or three minutes. http://jsfiddle.net/QvSng/6/

Answer (score 3):

To get the blur effect, use `filter: blur()` (with vendor prefixes). The blur applies only to the element itself, not to anything underneath it, so you'll need to reference the image within the "blur box" as well as in the background, and use `background-position` to control the offset so that they line up properly.

```
.blur {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/400/400');
    background-position: center -100px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zAKbP/)

Comment: YEAH! GREAT! Thank you so much! :) I'll accept, but can you please use this: background: url("*") no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;

Comment: I don't think this same concept will work for a background image that is scaled to fit the screen.  This was similar to what I did too, but I haven't gotten it to work with a non-fixed bg image size yet.

Comment: @andi: I already tried it, it work, but I think you work better ;)

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs - could you post a fiddle of it working with the scaled-to-fit bg image?  I'd like to see how it ended up.  I was having trouble scaling the blurred image in the middle column to exactly overlay the bg.

Comment: yeah - you're right.  I thought I tried that; I guess I had a typo somewhere.  oh well.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually apply blur for the `before` selector and inherit `background-image` instead of specifying url twice.

That makes the html structure more evident

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nbLcs241/)

Comment: I'd love to be able to do this with regular img elements too, but this is a great solution.